# How much can you save in Object/FileOutputStream

Tags: java, android

I find very little document to the limitations on this function. *SQL is still a little beyond my reach but yes I understand it is the godsend for data-storage*. Ignoring that, what are my limitations when writing to a file using the `Input/Output Streams`?
For instance I usually find that my projects only require one thing saved, a string or Array of some sort, which works fine for me, but:

- Can I save multiple types to the same file? Perhaps, a file with Objects, strings,
  doubles, floats, etc.?
- If so, when reading from the file, how do I discern one from the
  other?

Usually I use `retrieved_data = (datatype) obj_in.readObject();`, so, how do I know what I'm getting, if I saved multiple types of data to the file?

Documentation states that the method `.readObject()` "Reads the next object from the source stream."

Does that mean it stores it in the order I'm saving things?

Is there a standard for this kind of operation or is it all debatable preferences?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write any Serializable object with the [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html), they are stored in the same order as you write them, and should be read that way too:

> Multiple objects or primitives can be written to the stream. The
>   objects must be read back from the corresponding ObjectInputstream
>   with the same types and in the same order as they were written.

(Source: [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html))

Answer (score 0):

How about serialization and deserialization?
Using serialization you can store teh object values to a file and by using deserialization you can get the stored Objects.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that's what ObjectInput/OutputStream do.

Comment: exactly serialization is achieved using Object streams